# How can I automate the removal of kubernetes secrets from a yaml file?

Tags: regex, kubernetes, sed, yaml, yq

I have a file containing many Kubernetes YAML objects.
I am seeking a way of removing all K8s Secret YAML objects from the text file, identified by the `"kind: Secret"` string contained within the YAML block. This should remove everything from the "apiVersion" through to just before the "---" signifying the start of the next object.

I've looked into Sed, Python and yq tools with no luck.
The YAML may contain any number of secrets in any order.

How can I automate stripping out of these "Secret" blocks?

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  username: dGVzdAo=
  password: dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkCg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-1
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-site
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front-end
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    - name: rss-reader
      image: nickchase/rss-php-nginx:v1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 88
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  username: dGVzdAo=
  password: dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkCg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-2
type: Opaque
---
```

Comment: The best way is to use a proper YAML parser. Are there any "markers" identifying the beginning and end of each object? Other than the "---".

Comment: @virolino `---` is the way a compliant yaml parser would separate documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) can do this (and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) underneath)

```
pip install yq
```

```
yq --yaml-output 'select(.kind != "Secret")' input.yaml
```

You might need to remove the null document at the end of your example, it caused a little bit of weirdness in the output

***Note*** that there is also a different [`yq` utility](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) that doesn't seem to do what `jq` does so I'm not sure how to make that one work.

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/kislyuk/yq is the way to go for this usecase. mikeferah's yq has much better features, but doesn't work well for this. Raised a feature/bug request - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/476

Comment: @Inian yeah I wasn't quite sure how to approach it in the go yq as it seems to output different structure to the input which was confusing for me with multiple documents

Answer (score 0):

What about a shell script that splits the file at every occurrence of `---` by using the command **awk**? (See sections 5 and 6 of this [link](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html) for an example of that.) In this way, the script can evaluate each part separately and send those who do not correspond to `Secret` to a new output file.

Answer (score 0):

Purely with regex, you might search for

```
(^|---).*?kind: Secret.*?(---|$)
```

and replace with:

```
---
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/k1kVnu/1).

Note: at the end, you might have some extra `---` which you need to remove "manually" - but that should not be a big deal.